# pop index out of range in python?

Tags: python

I am trying to go through a list of urls and take a screenshot. Heres the code snippet.

```
 def onLoadFinished(result):
    #fo.write( column1[feed])#, column2[feed], urls[feed])
   global feed
   print urls

   if not result:
        print "Request failed"
    #print urls[feed]
    fo.write(str(column1[feed])+','+str(column2[feed])+','+str(urls)+','+'414'+','+'image not created\n')
    feed = feed + 1
        sys.exit(1)
        save_page(webpage, outputs.pop(0))   # pop output name from list and save
   if urls:
        url = urls.pop(0)   # pop next url to fetch from list
        webpage.mainFrame().load(QUrl(url))
    #print urls[feed]
    fo.write(str(column1[feed])+','+str(column2[feed])+','+str(urls)+','+'200'+','+'image created\n')
    feed = feed + 1
   else:
        app.quit()  # exit after last url

webpage.connect(webpage, SIGNAL("loadFinished(bool)"), onLoadFinished)
webpage.mainFrame().load(QUrl(urls.pop(0)))
#fo.close()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Now in webpage.mainFrame().load(QUrl(urls.pop(0))), I expect it to keep popping me the next url , but as soon as it enters the onloadfinished method it gives me the second url first time and then the list becomes empty and I get the error pop index out of rannge.

The url list is [1.2] .. It gives me 2 first and the second time it goes out of range. Any ideas how to get it in sequence from 1 and then 2 ?

Comment: Your indentation is somewhat... um.... interesting... Makes it a bit difficult to grok what's supposed to be going on...

Comment: Copied from notepad which for some reason messes the indentation. Do you still not get it ? I can edit it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`onLoadFinished` is also popping from `urls`, so if that runs first, when you get to the `webpage.mainFrame()` call that also pops from `urls`, the `1` has already been popped, and the second time there is nothing left to pop.

Comment: I don't have enough information to know what you are doing, but you are already calling `webpage.mainFrame().load(QUrl(url))` in `onLoadFinished`. Do you really need to call it again outside? What happens if you comment that line?

Comment: If I comment that code from outside, it just doesnt go into onloadfinished.

Comment: What if you don't do the pop inside `onLoadFinished`? Just comment out that line, since you aren't even using `url` in the function.

Comment: TypeError: arguments did not match any overloaded call:
  QUrl(): too many arguments
  QUrl(QString): argument 1 has unexpected type 'list'
  QUrl(QString, QUrl.ParsingMode): argument 1 has unexpected type 'list'
  QUrl(QUrl): argument 1 has unexpected type 'list'
Produces the above when I comment the pop inside. and do webpage.mainFrame().load(QUrl(urls)) instead

Comment: Oh, sorry, I didn't notice that use of `url`. Then don't comment, use `url = urls[0]` instead of popping. Although I don't understand why you are calling that function again. I was initially going to suggest commenting both (the popping and the load inside, and of course in that case also the `if urls:`).

Comment: That doesnt help. Now The pop outside the function return the 2nd value and inside the function it keeps calling the 2nd value over and over again.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34863/discussion-between-paulo-almeida-and-kuber-kaul)